# C Programming take "n" command line arguments and find the min of all arguments

Tags: c

I have a project that I am working on for my class and my teacher did not explain any of this very well. I really need help with it because I really have no idea how to go about it.

The assignment states that the program needs "to read n integers from the keyboard, where n should be given as a command line argument. "

It should look like this

```
./a.out 3
20 30 10
The smallest one is 10.
```

Where the 3 is n and 20, 30, and 10 are all entered by the user and then the program will find the minimum value of the entered ones.

Also my program needs to "check whether the number of the command line arguments and the value of n is correct or not. If not, you should provide an error information as the following example"

```
./a.out 10 20
Please input the number of integers as ./a.out number

./a.out 0    
Please input the number of integers as ./a.out number
```

He also gave us this "Hint: you may use the `int atoi(char *)` function to convert a string value to an integer
value."

Below is what I have gotten so far, but I have no idea how to related the command line arguments to n or vice versa. I'm very confused and could really use some help.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int num1, num2, min, max;

    if (argc == 2) {
        scanf("%d %d", &num1, &num2);
        if(num1>num2)
            max=num1, min=num2;
        if(num2>num1)
            max=num2, min=num1;

        printf("The smaller one is %d \n", min);
    }
}
```

Comment: you should know argc and argv

Comment: Please format your code

Comment: max=num1, min=num2; // are you sure about this statement and the one below. Also return is missing in int main

Answer (score 4):

```
./a.out 3
```

In this `argv[0]` represents the program name and 
 **`argv[1]`** will contain `3` .But **`argv[1]`** is a string so use `atoi` to convert it to `integer` and store it in `n`.

That was your teacher's hint to you .

Now as you got `n` now you can make use of it in your code to take `n` number of input.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code as per your requirement,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

int minimum;
if(argc != 2 )
{
    printf("Please input the number of integers as ./a.out number\n");
    return 1;
}
printf("enter the %d number", atoi(argv[1]));
int arr[atoi(argv[1])];
for(int i = 0; i< atoi(argv[1]); i++)
{
    scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
}

 minimum = arr[0];

    for ( int c = 1 ; c < atoi(argv[1]) ; c++ )
    {
        if ( arr[c] < minimum )
        {
           minimum = arr[c];

        }
    }
 printf("Minimum element is = %d\n",minimum);
}
```

- Hope this will help you.